# How to translate "In times of pain" to classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

My try is 'in temporibus doloris', with ablative form of 'tempus, temporis' and 'dolor, doloris' in the genitive. Is this right or should I maybe be using the dative for pain?

Answer (score 2):

I think your translation is spot-on.
The optimal choice depends on context, so my opinion might change if you give a complete sentence in which you want to use it.
As a general translation this would be my choice, too.
Genitive seems much more appropriate than dative in this phrase.

You can also phrase it in terms of the verb *dolere*, "to be in pain".
As Tom Cotton suggests in a comment, the participle *dolens* is possible.
Sometimes the gerund *dolendo* might be most appropriate; I might translate "we learn in times of pain" as *dolendo discimus*.
But if there is no sentence context and you want a standalone phrase, your choice is better.

Comment: As Joonas says, it is correct as it stands, but usage does indeed depend on context. The participle _dolens_ would be better if it qualifies the subject of the sentence as in, for instance, _dolens dormire semper volo_, 'I always want to sleep when I'm in pain'.